# Unable to access static resources for some profiles

Tags: apex, soql, static-resources, custom-profile, access

Unable to access static resources for some profiles who doesn't have **view and setup configuration**. I have a xml file in my static resources we query that static resources and do the processing with that xml in my app. Unfortunately the users who doesn't have access to **view and setup configuration** are unable to access that static resource via soql(fields are not accessible). I don't find any options to provide permissions to the profile do we have any setting where I could enable access for the profile instead of enabling **view and setup configuration**??

```
if(Schema.sObjectType.StaticResource.fields.body.IsAccessible()){ // Fails for profile whose "view and setup configuration" has been turned off
            StaticResource  xml = [select body from StaticResource where name = 'somedata'];
    }
```

Is this the expected behavior? To access staticresources from apex do the profile require **view and setup configuration** access.

**Note:** Im able to get the static resource from the browser for the same profile.

Comment: What is the access level on the Static Resource. Public/Private?

Comment: the access level is public

Answer (score 2):

Accessing Static Resources requires the "View and setup configuration" permission.

View more details about managing static resources and required permission to do same @ https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=pages_static_resources_manage.htm&type=5

Comment: This answer can be improved by a link / source.

Comment: I suspect that answer may be incorrect.  The question is regarding read access to the static resources in Apex code, not the administrative permission to define static resources.